# GCD with two big large numbers

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

How to find the $\gcd(2020^{1830} +2, 2020^{1830} -2)$? I can't seem to find the gcd because of the large numbers.

Comment: The size of the numbers is nearly irrelevant here.  Hint:  if $d=\gcd(a,b)$ then $d\,|\,(a-b)$.

Comment: The numbers are big but their difference is small.

Comment: You have vandalized your question, Karen, making the five answers that were posted irrelevant. Don't do that! Please roll your question back to the previous version. (By the way, the answer to the new question is "No", and an example is $n=4$.)

Comment: I took the liberty of rolling back the destructive edit.

Answer (score 4):

By the Euclidean algorithm,

$$(2020^{1830}+2,2020^{1830}-2)\to(2020^{1830}-2,4)^*\to(4,2)\to(\color{green}2,0)$$

---

$^*$It is obvious that $2020^{1830}=2^{1830}1010^{1830}$ is a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $2020^{1830}=a$. So you want $\gcd(a+2,a-2)$. Lets say this value be $d$. Thus, $d|a+2,d|a-2\implies d|4\implies d\in\{1,2,4\}$. But $4\not| a+2$ as $4|a$. Thus, $d\neq 4$ but $a+2,a-2$ are even, so $d=2$.

Comment: I think you want to say $4|a$. Nicely written down though.

Comment: @Zuy Yeah, fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b,a \bmod b)$ is key.

So your gcd equals $\gcd(2010^{1830}-2, 4)$ so ask yourself, what is the remainder of $2010^{1830}-2$ modulo $4$? It's clear that it's $2$ as the power is divisible by $4$. So we get $\gcd(4,2)=2$ in the end.

Answer (score 0):

$gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b+am)$ so

$gcd(2020^{1830}-2,2020^{1830}+2)$

$=gcd(2020^{1830}-2,2×2+(2020^{1830}-2))$

$=gcd(2020^{1830}-2,4)$

---

now consider $(2×1010)^{1830}-2=2^{1830}×1010^{1830}-2=2(2^{1829}×1010^{1830}-1)$ then obviously $gcd(2020^{1830}-2,4)=2$

so $gcd(2020^{1830}-2,2020^{1830}+2)=2$

Answer (score 0):

$$g = \gcd(2020^{1830} +2, 2020^{1830} -2)$$

Let $N = 2020^{1830}$. So you want $\gcd(N +2, N -2)$

If $g | N+2$ and $g | N-2$, then $g | (N+2)-(N-2)$, that is to say $g | 4$.

So $g$ must be $1, 2$ or $4$.

Since $2020$ is a multiple of $4$, then $4 | N$. Hence $ 4 \not | N+2$.

Hence $g=2$